# TextBoxes not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

i have a weird bug in my app that i've been working over two months. I know i should maybe paste some code but its probably pointless at this moment cause the bug spreads all over the application. Maybe it's silly but it drives me mad cause I can't move forward from here. Maybe someone encountered the same problem and know whats up. I'm pretty desperate at this moment and really dont know what to do.

the thing is - wherever i want to put a text box, its always disabled. It doesn't work anywhere. Every other control i'm using works perfectly, but the textboxes just stopped working. I have no idea... the text boxes i've had in the app, on other pages, work perfectly. I'm creating new pages and the boxes are always disabled on them. I know that the question is pretty general but i have no idea even which part of code to show, since the app is pretty big right now. It's really frustrating. Maybe i'm lucky and anybody has even a slightest idea of why the control can stop working on whole application all of the sudden?

UPDATE:

so what i've just realised is that the textbox usability depends on the container. It does'nt work in stackpanels and grids, but it does in listview. still don't know why though..

Comment: One possible reason is that there is a style in the application-wide `Resources` collection which sets the `IsEnabled` to false. Is it disabled even if you explicitly set `IsEnabled="True"` on the `TextBox` itself? Also, try using Snoop to check where the IsEnabled's value gets set.

Comment: @jimmy Habanero : Could you please put here code part so that we can easily identify your problem and can fix this.

Comment: I don't think it's the thing. Setting IsEnabled on specific textbox doesn't do anything so i'm guessing that there is no problem with styles, since it should be overriden when I set the property on the specific page. Ive checked on other pages that have had a working text box before and the on those pages even the new textbox works fine. only on the new pages, or pages that have never had a text box. it's really bizarre..

Comment: @GulMdErshad sory, but since i dont know where the bug is, i can't put any code.

Comment: @JimmyHabanero Try creating a smaller project, and duplicating the issue.

Comment: @JimmyHabanero Am I correct when I read that textboxes work on some pages, but not on others? are there any specific differences between the pages that do work, and those that don't? If so, please share.

Comment: the difference is that the textboxes are working when they are in list view but does not work in stackpanels and grids.

Comment: The only way forward here is to create a new minimal App and start to recreate the problem. Most likely you will find the cause yourself, otherwise you have something to post here. Right now it is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you use styles, and one of those styles somehow interferes with your textbox. Try commenting out styles until you find the culprit. Most probably it's a style applied to the whole application. You could move it in a more specific place.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at App.Xaml if there is any weird style define for StackPanels, Grids or TextBoxes. There can be a Style in the App.xaml file or in one if its MergedDictionary which can apply this affect throughout the application.

Or try below which clears all existing styles. Try setting Style to null for TextBox and StackPanel. If this works it's a styling issue which I guess it is.

Set null style only for one control at a time and see. If not working set for both and see...

```
<StackPanel Style="{x:Null}">
    <TextBox Style="{x:Null}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This wouldn't help if the parent `Panel` has a `Style` that sets the `Panel`'s `IsEnabled` to false. According to the question `TextBox` is disabled only in certain `Panels`. Maybe he can try setting `Style="{x:Null}"` on the parent `Panel` as well.